# syntax error in Insert into using MS Access in vb.net

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert, vb.net-2010

Encountering syntax error in `vb.net` using `MS Access` as my database. I am sure that it is not a syntax error since I already copied the command string to my `MS Access` and run it without any problem. The same command string was also used in my previous code without any problem. This is the actual command string I used inside `VB.net` (with problem) and in `MS access` (with no problem)

```
sComm = "Insert into Table1 (r_date,r_no,h_id,j_id,weight,position) values (#13/08/2017#,10,57,63,57.5,1)"

comm.CommandText = sComm
comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is also the same connection and command i used in other insert statement without any error. Hope somebody already has experienced with this kind of error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all use US date standard for dates: `#08/13/2017#`. yyyy/mm/dd format also works fine

Comment: It's probably a culture issue like @SergeyS. mentioned. So also make sure you're not running a culture where the decimal character is different from `.` (like `,`)

Comment: Is there syntax error? Your title says syntax error, then you say " I am sure that it is not a syntax error". I'm confused.

Comment: Vb.net is returning a "syntax error on insert". I just assumed that it`s not a syntax error since I run this same syntax on MS access and is running okay. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`POSITION` is a [reserved word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/248738/list-of-reserved-words-in-jet-4-0) in Access SQL so you need to enclose it in square brackets:

```vb
sComm = "Insert into Table1 (r_date,r_no,h_id,j_id,weight,[position]) values ...
```

Comment: Wow...thank you so much... It worked. I am already going insane for 1 week looking at what is wrong with the code.

Comment: I never thought of the reserved word since this is the same syntax that was run and running fine directly in MS Access...Again.. thank you thank you!!!